# How to print twitter data stream to a file whener ever i try,i am getting a unicode error

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

This is my python code to retrieve data from twitter.
but when I am trying to store the data to gannie.txt I am encountering the following error.

> ```
> File "D:\software\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: character maps to <undefined>
> ```
>
> Any help regarding this,i am new to this text mining and im trying to build project of sentiment analysis using natural language processing

here's my code:

```
outF = open("gannie.txt", "a")
for tweet in tweets:
    #print(tweet.text)
    Tweet = tweet.text
                #Convert www.* or https?://* to URL
    Tweet = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',Tweet)


    Tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','TWITTER_USER',Tweet)

                #Remove additional white spaces
    Tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', Tweet)

                #Replace #word with word Handling hashtags
    Tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', Tweet)

                #trim
    Tweet = Tweet.strip('\'"')

                #Deleting happy and sad face emoticon from the tweet 
    a = ':)'
    b = ':('
    Tweet = Tweet.replace(a,'')
    Tweet = Tweet.replace(b,'')

                #Deleting the Twitter @username tag and reTweets
    tag = 'TWITTER_USER' 
    rt = 'RT'
    url = 'URL'
    Tweet = Tweet.replace(tag,'')
    tweetCount+=1
    if rt in Tweet:
        continue
    Tweet = Tweet.replace(url,'')
    print(Tweet)
    outF.write(Tweet)
    outF.write("\n")
outF.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by just adding encoding="utf-8" to open file line

Before : `outF = open("gannie.txt", "a")`

After  : `outF = open("gannie.txt", "a",encoding="utf-8")`